# Changing plugin slug with update

Tags: updates

My plugin uses camelCase in file and folder like

```
myPlugin/myPlugin.php
```

I've encountered several issues with this on plugin updates. Most of them work just fine and it's more a cosmetic thing but on some places I just like to go with all lowercase.

What's the best way (or is there any) to update the plugin to

```
myplugin/myplugin.php
```

*without* hazzle the users?

Please note this is a custom plugin and not available on the repo and yes I had to do it lowercase in the first place.

Comment: "I've encountered several issues with this on plugin updates". What issues? I haven't found any issues that causes by file names.

Comment: WP uses the `slug` - which is always lowercase - to check if version is up to date, does exits etc. These checks are not required but disturb the UX. I know it will be disabled - which is the only problem - but how can I enable a "foreign" plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did some research/testing on it an in short terms:

**Don't use uppercase in the first place!**

I've currently noticed only one problem where the ajax based update from the plugins overview (introduced in WP 4.2) throws a JS error but it may be a problem in the future.

This is because the ajax response uses `sanitize_key` in the `wp_ajax_update_plugin` method ([browse in trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L3073)).

[The `sanitize_key` method](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src//wp-includes/formatting.php#L1486) does next to sanitization a `strtolower` which causes the "`myPlugin`" gets a "`myplugin`".

The [`updateSuccess`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src//wp-admin/js/updates.js#L200) method tries now to update the row where the slug is "`myplugin`" instead of "`myPlugin`".

This could be prevented by changing [line 694](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src///wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php#L694) in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php` from

```
    printf( "<tr id='%s' class='%s' data-slug='%s'>",
        $id,
        $class,
        $plugin_slug
    );
```

to

```
    printf( "<tr id='%s' class='%s' data-slug='%s'>",
        $id,
        $class,
        sanitize_key($plugin_slug)
    );
```

<del>*todo: open ticket*</del> [Ticket #35032](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35032)

**To answer the initial question**

You can change the slug on a plugin update but you have to take care of following:

- the following code must be included in the old version (eg.
  `myPlugin/myPlugin.php)
- the updated version **must** have a slug of `myplugin/myplugin.php
- don't use [`delete_plugin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_plugins/) which may trigger an uninstall.php and removes plugins data

Here's the code you can start with:

```
//hook into when new plugin has been successfully updated
add_filter( 'upgrader_post_install', 'my_move_plugin_slug', 10 ,3 );

function my_move_plugin_slug($should_be_true, $hook_extra, $result){

    global $wpdb, $wp_filesystem;

    $from = 'myPlugin/myPlugin.php';
    $to = 'myplugin/myplugin.php';

    //some general checks
    if(!$should_be_true || !isset($hook_extra['plugin']) || $hook_extra['plugin'] != $to) return $should_be_true;

    $old_destination = $result['local_destination'].'/'.dirname($from).'/';

    //old location doesn't exist (anymore)
    if(!is_dir($old_destination)) return $should_be_true;
    //new location is the same as the old one
    if($old_destination == $result['destination']) return $should_be_true;

    //do the magic

    //rewrite location in the database
    echo '<p>Moving the plugin to new location… ';
    if(false !== $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$wpdb->options} SET `option_value` = replace(option_value, %s, %s)", $from, $to))){
        echo '<strong>done</strong>';
    }
    echo '</p>';

    //delete folder
    echo '<p>Removing the old directory of the plugin… ';
    if($wp_filesystem->delete( $old_destination , true )){
        echo '<strong>done</strong>';
    }
    echo '</p>';

}
```

**Second method**

If you have a dedicate batch update progress in you plugin like I have you can use this code which is in my opinion a bit safer as it's triggered by explicit user interaction and doesn't require wp_filesystem:

```
function do_change_plugin_slug(){

    global $wpdb;

    $from = 'myMail/myMail.php';
    $to = 'mymail/mymail.php';

    $old_destination = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/'.$from;
    $new_destination = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/'.$to;

    //old location doesn't exist (anymore)
    if(!file_exists($old_destination)) return true;
    //new location is the same as the old one
    if($old_destination == $new_destination) return true;

    //do the magic

    echo 'Removing the old file of the plugin… ';
    if(rename( $old_destination , dirname($old_destination).'/'.basename($new_destination) )){
        echo 'done';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
    echo "\n";

    echo 'Removing the old directory of the plugin… ';
    if(rename( dirname($old_destination) , dirname($new_destination) )){
        echo 'done';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
    echo "\n";

    //rewrite location in the database
    echo 'Moving the plugin to new location… ';
    if(false !== $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$wpdb->options} SET `option_value` = replace(option_value, %s, %s)", $from, $to))){
        echo 'done';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
    echo "\n";

    return true;

}
```

In the end you should always make sure the user understands what's going on and/or why this is a necessary step.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to just change the filename you would have both `myPlugin.php` and `myplugin.php` in the plugin and then update the option `active_plugins` in the database to the new name. Once all of the users have updated you can remove  `myPlugin.php`.

But you want to rename both the folder and filename.

I would get `myPlugin/myPlugin.php` to install and activate `myplugin/myplugin.php`. Once `myplugin/myplugin.php` is installed `myplugin/myplugin.php` can delete `myPlugin/myPlugin.php`

You can use [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) for installing and activating the new plugin. Make to include a check so that the new and old version are not running at the same time.

You can use [`deactivate_plugins()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_plugins/) and [`delete_plugins()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_plugins/) to deactivate and uninstall the plugin.

Comment: Nice approach, thank you. I'm worried about the use of `delete_plugins()` since it's deletes plugins data with an uninstall.php file. See my answer to this for more info.

Comment: You could backup the data before deleting the old plugin and then restoring it afterwards.